# python splitting the rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am totally new to using python 
I am using a data frame in which one row needs to be split into two rows.
Both the rows will have same data except for one column

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. You could at least provide the data in a format which makes it easy **for other people to help you**. You also haven't explained what specifically the issue is, what you've tried, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we have a df:

```
df
   Column1 Column2 Column3
0        1      A1      A2
1        2      B1      B2
```

Then we can do:

```
df["Column4"] = df.apply(lambda x: [x[1],x[2]], axis=1)
df = df.explode("Column4")
print(df)

   Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
0        1      A1      A2      A1
0        1      A1      A2      A2
1        2      B1      B2      B1
1        2      B1      B2      B2
```

If contents of `Column1` is an issue we can go one step further:

```
df["Column1"] = range(1, df.shape[0]+1)
print(df)

   Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
0        1      A1      A2      A1
0        2      A1      A2      A2
1        3      B1      B2      B1
1        4      B1      B2      B2
```

Comment: If I execute the code once that it fine, if executed multiple times it produces double the result

Comment: @Himavari of cause it's supposed to be run once because `df` is mutated in the course of execution. If you want to run it again you need to start from scratch and redefine you `df` as it's  given in OP.

Answer (score 2):

here is another way without `apply`  using [`df.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) , [`series.droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.0rc1/api/generated/pandas.Series.droplevel.html) followed by [`df.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
m = df.set_index('Column1')
m = m.join(m.stack().droplevel(1).to_frame('Column4')).reset_index()
```

---

```
print(m)

   Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
0        1      A1      A2      A1
1        1      A1      A2      A2
2        2      B1      B2      B1
3        2      B1      B2      B2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
new_df = (df.reindex(df.index.repeat(len(df.columns)-1))
            .assign(Column4 = df[df.columns.difference(['Column1'])].stack().values))
print(new_df)
   Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
0        1      A1      A2      A1
0        1      A1      A2      A2
1        2      B1      B2      B1
1        2      B1      B2      B2
```